# Discord.js Bot Quiz Game: Issues with User Interaction and Score Handling

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to do this when the user uses/prog_quiz it will send a message in the channel hidden (ephemeral) and then the user can answer it if the user gets it wrong then remove 2 points but if the user gets it right add 2 points then it will show an another embed that goes titled continue or nothing if the user click confirm then new question will pop up and if user got it correct the continue or nothing will show again and continues, but if the user click cancel in double or nothing then nothing will happen but if the user got it wrong answer in continue or nothing then all points will deleted.

```
const response = await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [q_embed],
            components: [row],
            ephemeral: true,
        });

        const filter = i => i.customId === 'quiz' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect, time: 150000 });

        collector.on('collect', async (i) => {
            if (!i.isStringSelectMenu()) return;
            const userAnswer = i.values[0];
            const correctAnswerValue = `option_${randomQuestion.options.findIndex(option => option.label === randomQuestion.correctAnswer)}`;
            const correctOption = randomQuestion.options.find(option => option.label === randomQuestion.correctAnswer);

            if (userAnswer === correctAnswerValue) {
                user.points += 2; // plus two points
                await user.save();

                await i.reply({
                    content: 'Correct answer!' + ` The correct is **${correctOption.label} - ${correctOption.description}!**` + "\n" + "> **Greate!** You now have: `" + user.points + "`",
                    embeds: [],
                    components: [],
                    ephemeral: true
                });
                // confirm or cancel emebd of double or continue will show
                await wait(1000);
                await i.followUp({
                    content: "",
                    embeds: [c_embed],
                    components: [row2],
                    ephemeral: true
                });
                // Handle button clicks for "Continue or Nothing"
                const buttonCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
                    componentType: ComponentType.Button,
                    time: 150000
                });

                buttonCollector.on('collect', async (buttonInteraction) => {
                    if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'confirm') {
                        // User clicked "Continue"
                        const newRandomQuestion = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
                        const newSelect = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                            .setCustomId('newQuiz')
                            .setPlaceholder('Make a selection!')
                            .addOptions(newRandomQuestion.options.map((option, index) => ({
                                label: `Option ${option.label}`,
                                description: option.description,
                                value: `option_${index}`,
                            })));
                        const newRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(newSelect);

                        const newQuestionEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle('New Quiz Time!')
                            .setDescription(debug)
                            .setColor('Random');
                        // Ask a new question
                        await interaction.followUp({ content: '', embeds: [newQuestionEmbed], components: [newRow], ephemeral: true });
                    } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'cancel') {
                        // User clicked "Cancel"
                        // End the interaction
                        buttonCollector.stop();
                    }
                });

                buttonCollector.on('end', collected => {
                    console.log(`Button collector ended. Collected ${collected.size} items`);
                });

                cooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            } else {
                // await i.reply({ content: `Wrong answer! Goodluck next time...`, ephemeral: true });
                user.points -= 2; // minus 2 points if wrong answer
                await response.edit({ content: 'Wrong answer! Goodluck next time...', components: [], embeds: [] });
            }
            cooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        });

        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
        });

        // for continue or nothing
        const newFilter = m => m.customId === 'newQuiz' && m.user.id === interaction.user.id;
        const newCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect, time: 150000 });

        newCollector.on('collect', async (m) => {
            const newUserAnswer = m.values[0];
            const newCorrectAnswerValue = `option_${randomQuestion.options.findIndex(option => option.label === randomQuestion.correctAnswer)}`;
            const newCorrectOption = randomQuestion.options.find(option => option.label === randomQuestion.correctAnswer);

            if (newUserAnswer === newCorrectAnswerValue) {
                user.points += 2; // plus 2 points
                await user.save();
                
                await m.reply({
                    content: 'Correct answer!' + ` The correct is **${newCorrectOption.label} - ${newCorrectOption.description}!**` + "\n" + "> **Greate!** You now have: `" + user.points + "`",
                    embeds: [],
                    components: [],
                    ephemeral: true
                });
            } else {
                user.points -= 999999; // remove all points user have
                await user.save();

                await response.edit({ content: 'Wrong answer! Goodluck next time...', components: [], embeds: [] });
            }
        });

        newCollector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
        });
```

I expect the bot to function smoothly, displaying quiz questions as ephemeral messages, accurately calculating and updating user points, and handling user interactions seamlessly. Additionally, I want the continuation feature to work flawlessly, allowing users to progress through multiple questions while correctly managing their points and game state.